# For Angular 9 mat-tables, is there a way to set the CSS color for a row in just a single place?

Tags: css, angular, angular9, mat-table

In my mat-table (Angular 9), I want to have a function that determines the CSS class for each row ...

```
  getRowClass(item: Item): string {
    let class_ = "";
    if (...condition1...) {
        ...
    } else {
      class_ = 'warm';
    }
    return class_;
  }
```

The classes are fairly simple, and usually just consist of setting the color ...

```
.hot {
        color: red !important;
}
```

I configure the function for the row like so ...

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> category </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.category }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    ...
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="getRowClass(row)"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

However, I'm noticing with the mat-table, mat-cell defines its own "color" attribute.  One way to override it would be for each "<mat-cell *matCellDef" class to define

```
[ngClass]="getCSSClass(item)"
```

but this seems wasteful especially for tables that have many columns.  I would have to repeatedly hard-code this logic for each ng-container, when it is essentially doing the same thing for all.  Is there a more efficient way to override the mat-cell color attribute for an entire row?

Comment: Did you try to add "!important"?

Comment: seems some css overiding in your code otherwise the logic which you have used for mat-row calls should works fine and change the entire row background. `<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="getRowClass(row)"></mat-row> `

Comment: @oz1985oz, yes tried !important.  Updated my question to include it.  Still no difference.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example? I don't really understand your problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rph4cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to add `mat-cell` class as sub class of hot class because `mat-cell` class by default has `color` style

### Material style

```
.mat-cell, .mat-footer-cell {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
}
```

and you need add

```
.hot .mat-cell {
  color: blueviolet !important
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `class` attribute directly it should work, even without the `!important` statements.

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [class]="getRowClass(row)"></mat-row>
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/colorfull-material-row?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just returning a string try returning an object in this format - { 'classname': true }

```
getRowClass(item: Item): object {
  let class_ = "";
  if (...condition1...) {
      ...
  } else {
    class_ = 'warm';
  }
  return { class_: true };
}
```